# Read array in Awk

Tags: arrays, loops, awk

Created two arrays. I would like to print array 1 first record followed by all records in array 2 that matches array one primary key. The primary key is the third column in all arrays. I also have a column name. Similar to a transactional report.

Array 1

```
content1, content2, primaryKey1, content1, content1
content2, content2, primaryKey2, content2, content2
content3, content3, primaryKey3, content3, content3
```

Array 2

```
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3
datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2
datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2
```

Output

```
**content1, content2, primaryKey1, content1, content1**
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1
**content2, content2, primaryKey2, content2, content2**
datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2
datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2
**content3, content3, primaryKey3, content3, content3**
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3
data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3
```

Here is what I have so far but I can not figure out how to match the primary key

```
{
    for (i in Array1) 
    print Array1[i] > "output.csv"; 

    {for (k in Array2) 

        printArray2[k] > "output.csv"; 
    }
}
```

Here is how I am loading the array. Auth_num is the primary key. The file is not sort but I can do a sort command prior. The array I provided was just s sample. Not accurately data but similar structures and layout. The arrays are comma delimited. So thing of my goal as listing all transaction under an account. For example row one of array 1 would be the first account under that I would like to list all corresponding row in array matching on the shared primarykey1 value.

```
while (getline < "'"$Authorization"'")
        {
            split($0,ft,",");

            Auth_num=ft[4];
            request_date=ft[5];
            status=ft[8];
            state=ft[9];

    Authorization_Arr[Auth_num]=Auth_header","Auth_num","request_date","status","state;

}           

Updated code but no luck with it
for (key in Authorization_Arr)
        {   # now print the data for each key
            print "**"Authorization_Arr[key]"**"

            for (i in LineItem_Arr[key]) {
             print LineItem_Arr[i]
            }
        }
```

How I am populate the transaction array

while (getline < "'"$LineItem"'")
        {

```
        split($0,li,",");

        LI_Auth_num=li[4];      
        line_item_number=li[6];
        requested_from_date=li[7];
        requested_to_date=li[8];
        type=li[9];
        requested_date=li[10];
        determination_due_date=li[12];
        service_type=li[13];
        status=li[14];
        level_of_urgency=li[15];
        urgency_requested_by=li[16];
        primary_procedure=li[18];
        code=li[19];
        applied_eligibility=li[20];
        servicing_provider=li[21];
        provider_id=li[22];
        npi=li[23];
        in_network=li[24];
        servicing_provider_phone=li[26];
        place_of_service=li[28];
        comments=li[29];
        method=li[30];
        out_of_network_reason=li[31];
        preliminary_requested_units=li[33];
        request_source=li[34];
        determined_from_date=li[35];
        determined_to_date=li[36];
        determination=li[37];
        requested_units=li[39];
        recommended_units=li[40];
        determined_units=li[41];
        type_of_decision=li[42];


        LineItem_Arr[count]=LI_Auth_num","line_item_number","requested_from_date","type","requested_date","determination_due_date","service_type","status","level_of_urgency","urgency_requested_by","primary_procedure","code","applied_eligibility","servicing_provider","provider_id","npi","in_network","servicing_provider_phone","place_of_service","comments","method","out_of_network_reason","preliminary_requested_units","request_source","determined_from_date","determined_to_date","determination","requested_units","recommended_units","determined_units","type_of_decision;


    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `bash awk`. `bash` is a shell from which various commands can be called (e.g. sed, grep, awk). `awk` is a command which can be called from bash or various other shells or OSs (e.g. UNIX bash, UNIX ksh, Windows). Are you asking about bash arrays or awk arrays or something else? Also please indent your sample input/output by 4 spaces like you did your code so it's legible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ed. I am using a awk array.

Comment: Show in your code how you're populating the arrays rather than just listing the array contents as it's not clear how your arrays are populated given the rows of values in your question and `The primary key is the third column in all arrays`.

Comment: Are the records sorted by the _primary key_?

Comment: I updated my the question with the requested information. Correction the primary key is the 4 column.

Comment: Your question is far more confusing than it should be. You talk about 2 arrays and show some data, tell us the 3rd column is the key then say it's actually the 4th, provide code that access Array1 and Array2 but then show more code that populates just 1 array, Authorization_Arr, and uses variables that don't exist elsewhere in your posted code to do so, etc. Please just post a clear, simple, concise, testable example with sample input file(s), expected output, and the executable code you use to populate your array(s).

Comment: Honesty it is not that hard. I have two arrays. I need to loop through array 1 a row at a time. For each row in array 1 there are transactional records in array 2. I need to print the transactional record for each row in array 1 that matches on a primary key shared between the two array. So think of it like a bank account. Array 1 have 6 account and array 2 has all the transaction for each account. How do I print the account information in array 1 follow by a line break then all the transaction for that account. Of course I am using account# to match account and transaction

Comment: I am not looking for the actually code that directly for my project but just the structure of how I would do this with awk. So I apologize if my original question was confusing. Hopefully this is clearer

Comment: Both array are populated the same way. I did not think it was important how I populating the array beside I am using Auth_num as the key

Answer (score 0):

> I am not looking for the actually code that directly for my project but just the structure of how I would do this with awk.

Here's one approach (requiring GNU awk version 4). It first collects the transactions grouped by the key; thereafter, it's easy to print them for each key.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN { # initialize sample data
        Authorization_Arr["primaryKey1"] = "content1, content2, primaryKey1, content1, content1"
        Authorization_Arr["primaryKey2"] = "content2, content2, primaryKey2, content2, content2"
        Authorization_Arr["primaryKey3"] = "content3, content3, primaryKey3, content3, content3"
        Transaction_Arr[1] = "data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1"
        Transaction_Arr[2] = "data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1"
        Transaction_Arr[3] = "data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1"
        Transaction_Arr[4] = "data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3"
        Transaction_Arr[5] = "data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3"
        Transaction_Arr[6] = "data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3"
        Transaction_Arr[7] = "datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2"
        Transaction_Arr[8] = "datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2"

        for (i in Transaction_Arr)
        {   # collect the transaction indexes grouped by the key
            split(Transaction_Arr[i], a, ", ")
            Transaction_group[a[3]][length(Transaction_group[a[3]])+1] = i  # key is 3rd column
        }
        for (key in Authorization_Arr)
        {   # now print the data for each key
            print "**"Authorization_Arr[key]"**"
            for (i in Transaction_group[key]) print Transaction_Arr[Transaction_group[key][i]]
        }
      }
```

Comment: I get the error:  >>>    Transaction_group[a[2]][ <<< length(Transaction_group[a[2]])+1] = i
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed. The source line

Comment: What is your `awk` version?

Comment: I tried to update the loops can something like this work.  for (key in Authorization_Arr)
        {   
            print Authorization_Arr[key] > "output.csv"
            
   for (i in LineItem_Arr) 
   {
    (if Authorization_Arr[key,3]==LineItem_Arr[key,3]){
     print LineItem_Arr[i] > "output.csv"
    }
 
   }

        }

Comment: What I tried to do is check if the 3 field of a transactional array matches the 3 field of the Authorization array. So then I would print the matching transaction associated with the printed Authorization record.

Comment: What is your `awk` version?

Comment: good question, how would I determine my version on the command line?

Comment: `awk -V` or `awk --version` should do.

Comment: In the event that you can't get a modern `awk` implementation, I seized your suggestion in the comment above and implemented it in another answer.

Comment: I get the error : "A flag requires a parameter: v or Not a recognized flag:- when I type awk -V or awk --version.

Comment: Then your `awk` is really old.

Answer (score 0):

> can something like this work. for (key in Authorization_Arr) { print Authorization_Arr[key] > "output.csv" for (i in LineItem_Arr) { (if Authorization_Arr[key,3]==LineItem_Arr[key,3]){ print LineItem_Arr[i] > "output.csv" } } }

Well, something like this can work, but we can't simply refer to the third column in a line string as `…_Arr[key,3]`, since the lines haven't been split and assigned to separate array elements. Also it isn't possible to use the same arrays for the key elements, since that would cause the `for (… in …_Arr)` iterations to include the key elements. So, a working variant of your suggestion is to extract the keys into separate arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
function extract_key(array, key)
{
    for (e in array)
    {   
        split(array[e], a, ", ")
        key[e] = a[3]
    }
}

BEGIN { # initialize sample data
        Authorization_Arr["primaryKey1"] = "content1, content2, primaryKey1, content1, content1"
        Authorization_Arr["primaryKey2"] = "content2, content2, primaryKey2, content2, content2"
        Authorization_Arr["primaryKey3"] = "content3, content3, primaryKey3, content3, content3"
        LineItem_Arr[1] = "data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1"
        LineItem_Arr[2] = "data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1"
        LineItem_Arr[3] = "data1, data2, primaryKey1, data1, data1"
        LineItem_Arr[4] = "data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3"
        LineItem_Arr[5] = "data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3"
        LineItem_Arr[6] = "data3, data3, primaryKey3, data3, data3"
        LineItem_Arr[7] = "datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2"
        LineItem_Arr[8] = "datat2, data2, primaryKey2, data2, data2"

        extract_key(Authorization_Arr, Authorization_key)
        extract_key(LineItem_Arr,      LineItem_key)
        for (key in Authorization_Arr)
        {   print Authorization_Arr[key] >"output.csv"
            for (i in LineItem_Arr)
            {   if (Authorization_key[key]==LineItem_key[i]) print LineItem_Arr[i] >"output.csv"
            }
        }
      }
```